# Use a named range in an excel worksheet to propagate a listbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008, excel, vsto, excel-2003

So I have a number of namedRanges in an excel worksheet. I would like to use these to fill in comboboxes on a user form in the same WorkBook.

I have tried:

```
cboMember.DataSource = Globals.Sheet1.MemberRange.Value
```

No error is given but the combo is blank. Does anybody have any ideas?

I'm trying to use VSTO for VS 2008 on an excel 2003 work book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cboMember.RowSource = "NamedRange"

You don't set it to an object. Set it to a string. Excel figures out the rest.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a guess, but I believe in VBA you can do something like just `Range("MyRangeName")` to get the named range, so you could try the equivalent of that.

Some ranges in Excel are local to a sheet, some are global to the workbook. If they're local to a sheet then you'll need to prefix with sheet name, e.g. `Range("Sheet1!MyRangeName")`.

Comment: Thanks Rory

Globals.Sheet1.MemberRange.Value does return the correct values in an array but I cannot get my combobox to bind to it. I think I will have to loop through this array to assign the values to the combobox individually, something like

    cboMember.additem Globals.Sheet1.MemberRange.Value[i]

But I was thinking there must ba an easier way.

Comment: I think you're right that there's an easier way. How about binding a combobox manually then see how it looks when you inspect it with VBA/debugger?